# Identifying a record in a constantly changing table

Tags: automation, qtp, hp-uft

I'm using HP-UFT to automate some smoke tests for a web application. I create a record and then subsequently delete this record. The table changes on a daily basis and thus the record will be on a different row each day. I haven't been able to find a way to dynamically identify the row. Could someone shed some light on this?

Regards

Comment: Do you know any data from this record? or can you save some data in the process that will be in this record?

Comment: If you have the table, can't you simply perform a loop on each row until you find the record?

Comment: Yes i know the data from the record

Comment: If it's a `WebTable` object you're looking for, get its `Rowcount` and iterate over the rows (use `GetCellData`) till you find the row you are looking for.  Can't be more specific than that unless you edit the question to give more information regarding the AUT and information you are looking for.